# Error while installing shiny package in R

Tags: r

This is my code:

```
install.packages("shiny")
```

Then in the output its showing like this:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/werd/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘Rcpp’, ‘bitops’, ‘httpuv’, ‘caTools’, ‘RJSONIO’,           ‘xtable’, ‘digest’, ‘htmltools’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/Rcpp_0.11.2.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1600 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1600 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/bitops_1.0-6.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1600 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1600 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/httpuv_1.3.0.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1596 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1596 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/caTools_1.17.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1598 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1598 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/RJSONIO_1.3-0.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1598 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1598 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/xtable_1.7-3.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1600 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1600 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/digest_0.6.4.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1596 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1596 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/htmltools_0.2.4.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1598 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1598 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/shiny_0.10.1.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1596 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1596 bytes

Warning in install.packages :
error 1 in extracting from zip file
Warning in install.packages :
cannot open compressed file 'Rcpp/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or   directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

The last part of the output of the program is showing the error.
I went to the target folder and found that no zip file is downloaded.
Also, i am having winzip with me.

The last part of output of program is:

```
Warning in install.packages :
error 1 in extracting from zip file
Warning in install.packages :
cannot open compressed file 'Rcpp/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or   directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

Kindly help me what to do.

Comment: Maybe try selecting a different repo and trying again: `chooseCRANmirror()`

Comment: Do you have enough space on the disk?

Comment: Yes Pascal, I have enough space on disk. I think my proxy is creating some issues. Any suggestions on how to get rid of that?

Answer (score 0):

Go Directly to "http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/shiny_0.10.1.zip"

Download the file on your laptop/PC .

Then run the command:

install.packages(shiny_0.10.1.zip, repos=NULL)

Answer (score 0):

Check these solutions (They are the results of my Googling):

1.
Change your repository to another repositories (domestic repositories are better.)

2.
Just update manipulate:

```
install.packages("manipulate")
```

Then:

```
install.packages("shiny")
```

3. change working directory and try again.
4. download manually the shiny package and install with this command:
   install.packages('D:/shiny_0.11.1.zip', repos = NULL, type = "source")